# Two Outlook Profiles Simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have added two profiles under Control Panel --> Mail to configure two Microsoft Exchange email accounts.

When I open Outlook, it does prompt to choose the profile, my question is that is it possible to open two profiles simultaneously?

Appreciate any insight or help.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Why do you need to have two profiles? While you can load only one profile at a time,  you can add multiple accounts to one profile.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am using Windows 7.

Comment: There used to be an executable you could use that makes this work called ExtraOutlook. Not sure where to find it, etc. but should be simple enough for you to Google, download, AV scan, and then test and use. While by default this is not supported or how Outlook is supposed to work, I have seen this work just fine with my own eyes in the past. There may be another way to emulate the logic however ExtraOutlook works to make this happen as well. You might clarify what version of Outlook you need this to work from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, it is not possible to open 2 Outlook profiles simultaneously**.

You can change the option in Control Panel -> Mail to prompt you for which profile you want to open every time you start Outlook.

**Having 2 profiles is not a requirement for having two Microsoft Exchange accounts in Outlook 2010 or newer**. However, you should make sure your primary Exchange account is added to your Outlook profile first. There are certain limitations (albeit minimal) when the second Exchange account is added to an existing profile. One of them being you can't remove the first account once the second account is added, and the rest elude me at the moment.

I run at least 2 exchange accounts on a single profile in Outlook 2016 (and have since 2013) and don't notice any drawback whatsoever.

Comment: Another drawback of this solution: You cannot add Shared Mailboxes. The button "Add" is greyed out.

Comment: @MHeld It’s unclear what you are referring to. I have 3 exchange accounts loaded with no less than 10 shared mailboxes in my outlook. You don’t need to “Add” anything. When a user is granted full permission to a shared mailbox it shows up automatically in Outlook, but you can certainly still add it in your account settings.

Answer (score 1):

The drawback which I found, is that you cannot have o365 groups added to outlook from the second account, which has been added. Outlook seems to only support groups from the primary account in the profile.